# Prioritize string validation messages

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

In PHP, how can we prioritize the result message of one check over the other?

I have two different if conditions in my PHP file with two different messages.

Some strings match both, but even if the `if (preg_match)` is located above `if !(preg_match)` in the script, the result shows the error msg of  `!(preg_match)`

Example:

```
if (preg_match('/^[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]*$/u', $value)){
$return = $register_msg['ihc_error_please_write_yourname_in_english'];
}
if (!preg_match('~[eyuioa]~',$value)) {
$return = $register_msg['ihc_error_no_vowels_found'];
}
```

Now when a user enters his name via Arabic characters for example, although his string matches both conditions, unfortunately he gets `['ihc_error_no_vowels_found']` instead of getting `['ihc_error_please_write_yourname_in_english']`.

Comment: i updated the post with an example

Comment: I have edited your question using markdown instead of html and rephrasing some parts a little. Feel free to roll back if you don't like.

Comment: that's ok. thank you

Comment: What's missing is one of the names that cause the faulty behaviour. I have a suspicion that it doesn't entirely consist of arabic letters (e.g. containing spaces) thus doesn't actually match the first condition. Other than that if both conditons are true, `$return` will be overwritten by the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
$register_msg = ['ihc_error_please_write_yourname_in_english' => 'English, please!', 'ihc_error_no_vowels_found' => 'No vowels!' ];
$value = 'سبعة';

$return = "";
if (preg_match('/^[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]*$/u', $value)){
    $return .= $register_msg['ihc_error_please_write_yourname_in_english'] . PHP_EOL;
} else if (preg_match('~^[A-Za-z]+$~',$value) && !preg_match('~[eyuioa]~',$value)) {
    $return .= $register_msg['ihc_error_no_vowels_found'] . PHP_EOL;
}

echo $return;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/1Q6PZS) that with an Arabic word yields

```
English, please!
```

And with `SFGH` value (see [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/8V6Wgr)) yields

```
No vowels!
```

The `preg_match('~^[A-Za-z]+$~',$value)` checks if the string only consists of 1+ ASCII letters.

Comment: sorry i am new to stackoverfow. i did it right now.